# "cross product" but raise to exponent instead of multiply

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, cross-product

I have two vectors. I would like a "cross product"-esque function that will take each value from the first vector and raise it to the exponent of each value in a second vector, returning a matrix. Is there anything built in to numpy that does this? It could be done with loops but I'm looking for something efficient.

For example:

```
>>> cross_exp([1,2], [3,4]) 
[[1, 1],[8, 16]]
```

Comment: Given your expected output, it sounds like you're asking for an "outer product"-like function rather than a "cross product"-like function (do correct me if I've misunderstood).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you might want `np.power.outer`:

```
>>> np.power.outer([1,2], [3,4])
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 8, 16]])
```

Most ufuncs have an [`outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) method which computes the  result of the operation on all pairs of values from two arrays (note this is different to the cross product).